# How to remove/delete files from my shared folder in Google drive?

Tags: google-drive

How can we remove or delete files from shared folder in Google Drive as I can't see any remove/delete option there. See the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Here I want to remove ymusic-latest.apk from my shared folder. How do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Remove options as shown on the first image below. If not (as is your case), then long-press on the file, a menu should appear as seen on the second image. You can then click on the trash/bin to delete the file.

I used version 2.19.392.02.35 of Google Drive.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: I tried it too, but strangely no delete option appeared.

Comment: I simply deleted this file from desktop version of google drive.

Comment: @user3779493 What about other files? Does the Remove option appear for them? Have you tried to clear the app's cache?

Comment: I had only one file in shared folder. Yes I did clear app's cache and updated the app too but nothing worked for me. The desktop version of this app did the job for me.